# Is white/brown-out effect hazardous during the landing roll out?

Tags: landing, runways, visibility

Landing on unpaved runways or runways covered by snow or dust causes a white/brown-out visibility restriction.

Does it disrupt the pilot's visibility during the roll out in a fixed-wing aircraft?

Comment: In my experience landing single engine tractor, high wing airplanes on very dry, dusty sand and clay surfaces, as well as snowy surfaces, no. I think the danger lies in visibility impairment to rotorcraft pilots, as well as FOD damage to airframes or powerplants.

Comment: Whiteout can be a significant hazard to aircraft using reverse thrust to slow.

Answer (score 1):

From a partial accident list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownout_(aeronautics)#Partial_list_of_related_accidents), the issue seems to affect only helicopters.

A fixed wing rolling out should have no issue. As the dust/snow cloud will be behind the windshield. A plane landing in sequence should wait until the dust/snow settles.

Also an approach in poor visibility caused by a sandstorm would be no different than an approach in fog. An instrument approach will be carried out.